# Unit tests for completion & error blocks for server calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, cocoa-touch, xctest

I am trying to write unit tests for one of the method in my class. This method makes a server call and passes completion & error block. I know how to make asynchronous server calls from test class but my doubt is how do I test the method which makes the server call with completion & error blocks. Here the intention is to check if the completion & error blocks are handling the server response correctly or not.

If anyone has done this before then please guide. Please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

Below is an example of one such method. Here, I want to write a unit test which could test 'fetchItems' method both for success and error handling cases.

```
- (void)fetchItems {
    __weak MyListController *aBlockSelf = self;
    NSDictionary *aPostBody = @{kMyCategoryId : self.categoryId};

    // Fetch Items List From Server
    self.requestHandler = [[MyRequestHandler alloc] initWithEndPoint:[kMyFetchQuickListCategoryProductsURLKey  MyEndPoint] body:aPostBody container:self.view loadingOverlayTitle:nil successHandler:^(NSDictionary *iResponse) {
        if (iResponse) {
            aBlockSelf.isInfoData = [iResponse boolForKey:@"infoData"];
            aBlockSelf.isTestEnabled = [iResponse boolForKey:@"enabled"];
            NSArray *categoryData = iResponse[@"categoryData"];
            NSArray *itemList = categoryData[0][@"items"];

            NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kMySortOrderKey ascending:YES];
            aBlockSelf.itemList = [MyListData quickListDataArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[itemList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[aSortDescriptor]]] withInventory:@10 andISInfoData: aBlockSelf.isInfoData];
        }

        [aBlockSelf fetchImages];
        [aBlockSelf refresh];
    } andErrorHandler:^(NSString *iMessage, NSString *iKey, NSInteger iErrorCode, BOOL iIsNetworkError) {
        MySessionObject.selectedCategory = nil;

        ([aBlockSelf.alertView isVisible]) {
            [aBlockSelf.alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.alertView.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
        }

        aBlockSelf.alertView = nil;

        if (iIsNetworkError) {
            aBlockSelf.alertView = [[MyUIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:iMessage cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" cancelButtonActionHandler:^{
                [aBlockSelf dismissViewController];
            } otherButtonTitle:nil andOtherButtonActionHandler:nil];

            [aBlockSelf.alertView show];
        }

        aBlockSelf.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
        aBlockSelf.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    }];

    [self.requestHandler executeRequest];
}
```

Comment: Some example code would be useful.

Comment: @TomaszBąk : Thank you for responding. I am still having doubt on the exact implementation. I've added a sample method I am trying to write a test case for. Could you please explain with reference to this method.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you have a server request mixed with your model, you should separate it with a new object or an abstract interface. Thanks to this, while testing, you can stub your server to send fixed responses. Let's say you have separated sending a request into this object:

```
@interface ServerCommuncation : NSObject

- (void)request:(id)request completion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion;

@end
```

Now in your unit test you can inject your stub:

```
@interface ServerCommuncationStub : ServerCommunication

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completion)(NSError *error);

@end

@implementation ServerCommuncationStub

- (void)request:(id)request completion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion {
    self.completion = completion;
}
```

and you call completion whenever it suits you:

```
ServerCommuncationStub *stub = [ServerCommuncationStub new];
Model *model = [[Model alloc] initWithServerCommunication:stub];
[model request];
stub.completion(nil);
```

Even better way is using mocking library. I personally use OCMockito. You can have the same effect without subclassing:

```
ServerCommuncation *mock = mock([ServerCommuncation class]);
Model *model = [[Model alloc] initWithServerCommunication:mock];
[model request];

MKTArgumentCaptor *captor = [MKTArgumentCaptor new];
[verify(mock) request:anyting() completion:[captor capture]];
void(^block)(NSError *error) = [captor value];
block(nil);
```

You can find many useful informations about making your code testable in [Refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) and [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44919.Working_Effectively_with_Legacy_Code)